# Can not install scikit_learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I want to get into ML and am trying to install scikit via pip.

I have pandas, numpy and scipy installed and can use them.
I also have cython installed.
I am using the latest python version 3.10.1.
I upgraded the setuptools and did the same for pip.
For my project its important to use opensource libaries.

What am I missing?
Many Thanks in advance.

The following messages I get:

```
C:\Users\morit>pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz (6.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
```

After installing Microsoft Visiual C++ latest version. Unfortunate I still can not install scikit.

```
    C:\Users\morit>pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz (6.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwrdv342v'
       cwd: C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_7638cf0d3e734f2d96e709bd91706393
  Complete output (56 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj
  test_program.c
  test_program.c(1): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "stdio.h": No such file or directory
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 507, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 88, in <lambda>
      m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 171, in CCompiler_spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError('Command "%s" failed with exit status %d%s' %
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 319, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 315, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 201, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage("sklearn")
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-o9bfbedm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 85, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_7638cf0d3e734f2d96e709bd91706393\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 47, in cythonize_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_7638cf0d3e734f2d96e709bd91706393\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 113, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_7638cf0d3e734f2d96e709bd91706393\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 70, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 403, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/7c/596ff7b32f655f379d3abdfa82607e5cb3b70f46baad4604706511cfeb85/scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=ac2ca9dbb754d61cfe1c83ba8483498ef951d29b93ec09d6f002847f210a99da (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwrdv342v' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.tar.gz (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfrvhwkio'
       cwd: C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_6f5ce3b939c44daebde31f82bdc425f1
  Complete output (56 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj
  test_program.c
  test_program.c(1): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "stdio.h": No such file or directory
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 507, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 88, in <lambda>
      m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 171, in CCompiler_spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError('Command "%s" failed with exit status %d%s' %
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 319, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 315, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 201, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage("sklearn")
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pyad4_ys\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 85, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_6f5ce3b939c44daebde31f82bdc425f1\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 47, in cythonize_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_6f5ce3b939c44daebde31f82bdc425f1\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 113, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_6f5ce3b939c44daebde31f82bdc425f1\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 70, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 403, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/4d/15c3542a17eebf61e48bd71dc55b5f3b5031f1cd0dc4aad1ff9ac9651e49/scikit-learn-1.0.tar.gz#sha256=776800194e757cd212b47cd05907e0eb67a554ad333fe76776060dbb729e3427 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfrvhwkio' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpncoezmhd'
       cwd: C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_52d98203cf264f69aa4bc128ae995672
  Complete output (56 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj
  test_program.c
  test_program.c(1): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "stdio.h": No such file or directory
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 507, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 88, in <lambda>
      m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 171, in CCompiler_spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError('Command "%s" failed with exit status %d%s' %
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 301, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 297, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 188, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vyx5hgpq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 83, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_52d98203cf264f69aa4bc128ae995672\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 45, in cythonize_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_52d98203cf264f69aa4bc128ae995672\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 106, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_52d98203cf264f69aa4bc128ae995672\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 66, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(['test_program.c'], output_dir='objects',
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 403, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/04/507280f20fafc8bc94b41e0592938c6f4a910d0e066be7c8ff1299628f5d/scikit-learn-0.24.2.tar.gz#sha256=d14701a12417930392cd3898e9646cf5670c190b933625ebe7511b1f7d7b8736 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpncoezmhd' Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.24.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\morit\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.7.3)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\morit\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.21.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpglardw38'
       cwd: C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_81eb5676473f436f8db81ae9696fde4d
  Complete output (58 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj
  test_program.c
  test_program.c(1): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "stdio.h": No such file or directory
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 401, in compile
      self.spawn(args)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 507, in spawn
      return super().spawn(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 88, in <lambda>
      m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 171, in CCompiler_spawn
      raise DistutilsExecError('Command "%s" failed with exit status %d%s' %
  distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 306, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 302, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 188, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-bst370zd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 83, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_81eb5676473f436f8db81ae9696fde4d\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 45, in cythonize_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_81eb5676473f436f8db81ae9696fde4d\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 106, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1j5fcmi\scikit-learn_81eb5676473f436f8db81ae9696fde4d\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 66, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(['test_program.c'], output_dir='objects',
    File "C:\Users\morit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 403, in compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\include /Tctest_program.c /Foobjects\test_program.obj" failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: `distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` <- this tells you all you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+scikit-learn+Python+3.10

Comment: The current latest version https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.0.1/#files supports Python 3.7 up to 3.9 but not 3.10. Either compile from sources or downgrade your Python.

Comment: @Blowsh1t https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-390/

Comment: Hello I resolved the problem. I am sorry for posting a duplicate or missleading question. The following steps solved my issue: 1. Install Python 3.9 NOT 3.10 2. Install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools. 3. pip install scikit-learn. Many Thanks for telling me about the python version and the c++ build tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix this error:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

You can fix it by following these links:

[Visual Studio Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

[Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Latest Supported Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)

Comment: I did and a new error occured. I will update the question.